# How do I start a second animation in the blend file?

Tags: animation

so I know I can create an animation and save it with a fake user in the dope sheet, but how do I start a second animation so I can save that as well?

Comment: In the action editor click on the x near the action's name then click on new.

Comment: or simply click on new  ;)